# Does Sharepoint API allow 3rd party database calls?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, external-data

I am recreating an old intranet site using Sharepoint.  I have created a few lists in Sharepoint that will be used to show data.  Now, I am trying to populate these lists with the same data from the old intranet site.

All of the Sharepoint API logic that I see is for pulling/putting data with sharepoint. Does Sharepoint support making API calls to external databases and populate the lists with this data?  Or do I need to recreate the old intranet data in the Sharepoint lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is likely to store the data using SharePoint lists and libraries.

You could utilise Business Connectivity Services (BCS) and external content types to display the data via external lists but this is less desirable. External lists require far more configuration and could have performance issues.

Comment: Makes sense.  I appreciate you giving an answer.